# LogParser 2.2 Unable to get Filesize

Tags: logparser

Currently trying to get the folder sizes So I can compare 2 directories with Long File names.

It was recommended that I should use Log Parser as it will show files longer then 256 Characters. However when I run the command I get a syntax error that I'm Not sure how to fix.

```
 LogParser "SELECT EXTRACT_PREFIX(Path, 1, '\\') AS Folder, SUM(Size) FROM C:\*.*  GROUP BY Folder
```

The error i get is

```
WARNING: Input format not specified - using TEXTLINE input format.
Error: SELECT clause: Syntax Error: unknown field 'Path'

To see valid fields for the TEXTLINE input format type:
LogParser -h -i:TEXTLINE
```

Any help would be appreciated! or if you can suggest an alternative way to compare 2 directorys Folder sizes with Long file names that would be great

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, Needed to add the -i:FS tag to the end

Correct Code is

```
 LogParser "SELECT EXTRACT_PREFIX(Path, 1, '\\') AS Folder, SUM(Size) FROM C:\*.*  GROUP BY Folder" -i:FS
```